# Debugging a Typescript Preact app with VS Code

Tags: typescript, preact

For education I have set up a preact application using the [recommended way](https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/getting-started):

```
preact create typescript preactTS
```

This went fine and the resulting project could be opened in VS Code. To run it I changed the `dev` script in package.json to:

```
"dev": "preact watch -H localhost -p 3001 --clear false",
```

and added a launch config:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch preactTS on Chrome",
            "url": "http://localhost:3001",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "userDataDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/chrome",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
                "webpack:///*": "${workspaceFolder}/src/*",
                "webpack:///./*": "${workspaceFolder}/src/*"
            },
            "showAsyncStacks": true,
        }
    ]
}
```

And my tsconfig.json:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2022",
        "module": "esnext",
        "allowJs": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "jsxFactory": "h",
        "jsxFragmentFactory": "Fragment",
        "removeComments": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "react": [
                "./node_modules/preact/compat"
            ],
            "react-dom": [
                "./node_modules/preact/compat"
            ]
        },
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "sourceRoot": "src",
        "lib": [
            "es2022",
            "dom"
        ],
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": false,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": false,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": []
}
```

After that I was able to launch the web app in a Chrome instance. Now I want to debug the app and as you can see in the launch config I already added map path overrides. With these entries my breakpoints validate, however execution does not stop there and I don't know why.

Adding a `debugger` statement works however, and once the debugger stopped there I can step through the code. But even then new breakpoints still don't work.

What's the recommended setup to make debugging a Preact app work in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to set an option in the launch config, which is not used very often (at least there are not many useful results when searching for it):

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch preactTS on Chrome",
            "url": "http://localhost:3001",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "userDataDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/chrome",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
                "webpack://*": "${workspaceFolder}/src/*",
            },
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--allow-insecure-localhost"
            ],
            "showAsyncStacks": true,
            "smartStep": true,
            "perScriptSourcemaps": "no"
        }
    ]
}
```

Per script source maps must be disabled, apparently.